# Display Wordpress shortcodes over REST API to Native App

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I'm trying to display one important shortcode over Rest API to my Native Android App but it's not displaying anything. It comes up blank and I don't know why.

I am using a WilCity theme that comes with Native Apps built via expo.

`[sphere url="blabla"]` required shortcode.

I just need to get the shortcode to display on the Native App via REST API for the custom post type "listing".